# How to write xpath for enabled item

Tags: java, xpath

In my scenario multiple element are in same xPath but only one element is enabled and remaining all are disabled. How to select that particular enabled element.

Disabled:

```
<input id="UpdateBankDetails(True)_78775" name="BankDetails" onclick="UpdateBankDetails(this)" type="radio" value="True" disabled="">
```

Enabled:

```
<input checked="checked" id="UpdateBankDetails(False)_78779" name="BankDetails" onclick="UpdateBankDetails(this)" type="radio" value="False">
```

How do I write xPath to select the enabled element?

Comment: Use an xpath predicate based on the attribute which specifies whether the element is disabled.

Comment: @enabled checks for something like <xmlAttribute enabled >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find an input that does not have `disabled` attribute defined:

```
//input[not(@disabled)]
```